# How to submit a print job using Graph v5.0 SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Some of the implementations are changed in Graph .net sdk v5.0.
Previously with v4.0 sdk, I can create a job by calling, createJob:

```
var createPrintJob = await graphClient
                        .Print
                        .Shares[shareId]
                        .Jobs
                        .Request()
                        .AddAsync(printJob)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

then, upload the job data.
How to do that in sdk v5.0? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a bug in SDK v5.0. I can reproduce the issue.

`PrinterShareItemRequestBuilder` - request builder for `printJob` resource is missing in the client library.

Bug reported [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1823):